# cfml error with application.cfc page

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

I have some problem with my cfml website.

I have used the below code in application.cfc file to connect with the dsn.

But when ever i put this in my server, i'm getting error. i cant browse even a single test.cfm page.

Is there any mistake in that code , any syntax error or something like that, will it be some problem with the dsn

```
<cfset this.name = "0307de6.netsolhost.com">
<cfset this.sessionmanagement = true>
<cfset this.loginstorage="session">
<cfset this.sessiontimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)>
<cfset this.applicationtimeout = CreateTimeSpan(2,0,0,0)>

<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">

    <cfscript>
        application.DSN             = "hirerodsn";
        application.dbUserName      = "myusr";
        application.dbPassword      = "myd69!";
    </cfscript>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onRequestStart">

    <cfscript>
        request.DSN = "hirerodsn";
        request.dbUserName = "myusr";
        request.dbPassword = "myd69!";
    </cfscript>

</cffunction>
```

please anyone help me

Comment: Does the DSN (hirerodsn) exist on your live server? Give me some error message please

Comment: The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.

Null Pointers are another name for undefined values.

Comment: Is the CF version the same on dev and prod?

Comment: i dont know much about this, if its different whats the problem??

This was working fine in other server, and we have now changed our host now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you should also post at least error messages in your questions.

Any way, your error here is that you have to enclose whole .cfc file contents inside *cfcomponent* tag:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
...
</cfcomponent>
```

Also please note that you can set the username and password in datasource configuration, so you don't really need to handle them in your code (queries).

Comment: CF9 doesn't throw an error if the component declaration in application.cfc is missing. Copied the code over to my server and it works for me. Agree, that an error message would be helpful. It also would be good to know, on which environment the app is running on.